# adding a count next to an aggregated data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have data in a csv that needs to be parsed. It looks like:

```
Date,Tag,Amount
13/06/2018,ABC,6750000
13/06/2018,ABC,159800
24/05/2018,ABC,-1848920
16/05/2018,AB,-1829700
16/05/2018,AB,3600000
28/06/2018,A,15938000
16/05/2018,AB,3748998
28/06/2018,A,1035000
28/06/2018,A,1035000
14/06/2018,ABC,2122717
```

what I am trying to achieve is to make the date and tag the key and group by the date and tag and to sum up the amount. this is working for me, however, I want to show the count next to each record to show how many data set has been put together.

expected result

```
Date,Tag,Amount,Count
13/06/2018,ABC,6909800,2
24/05/2018,ABC,-1848920,1
16/05/2018,AB,5519298,3
28/06/2018,A,18008000,3
14/06/2018,ABC,2122717,1
```

the code I am using now is grouping by the date and tag and summing up the amount but it does not show the count.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for line in z:
    tokens = [t.strip() for t in line.split(",")]
    try:
        date = tokens[0]
        tag = tokens[1]
        amount = int(tokens[2])
    except ValueError as e:
        continue
    d[date][tag] += amount

s = '\n'.join(['{0} {1} {2}'.format(k, k2, v2) for k,v in d.items() for k2,v2 in v.items()])

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(s)
```

could someone show me how to achieve this please without using pandas

thanks

Comment: You asked the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a library called `pandas`, which can be used to do your task

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
df.groupby(by=['Date', 'Tag']).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (date,tag) tuple as a dict key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: [0,0])
for line in z:
    # z is an iterator over the csv lines
    try:
        tokens = tuple(t.strip() for t in line.split(","))
        d[tokens[:2]][0] += int(tokens[2]) 
        d[tokens[:2]][1] += 1
    except ValueError as e:
        continue

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k,v in d.items():
        f.write(','.join(map(str, list(k) + v)) + '\n')
```

Comment: are you able to show me how to link this in with my code? i tried it but it is not working

Comment: okay, but z is assumed to be an iterator over the csv lines. Edited!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant where everything is performed "manually", using a regular *dict*. Note that it's neither elegant (or short), nor fast.

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys


def main():
    d = dict()
    with open("./in.csv") as fin:
        for line in fin:
            tokens = line.strip().split(",")
            try:
                date = tokens[0]
                tag = tokens[1]
                amount = int(tokens[2])
            except ValueError as e:
                continue
            key = date, tag
            value = d.get(key, [0, 0])
            value[0] += amount
            value[1] += 1
            d[key] = value

    if d:
        with open("./out.csv", "w") as fout:
            fout.write("Date,Tag,Amount,Count\n")
            for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
                fout.write("{:},{:},{:},{:}\n".format(*key, *value))
    else:
        print("Nothing to write")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Output**:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054440237>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054440237>type out.csv
> Date,Tag,Amount,Count
> 13/06/2018,ABC,6909800,2
> 14/06/2018,ABC,2122717,1
> 16/05/2018,AB,5519298,3
> 24/05/2018,ABC,-1848920,1
> 28/06/2018,A,18008000,3
> ```

Comment: Hi Crisit, could you show me how to use your example with mine? i tired to merge your example with my code but it isnt working. thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what to merge. This is a complete example which works on its own (as shown in the output). The only thing you'd probably need to change it's the filename that contain s the input data: (`with open("./in.csv") as fin:`) from *"./in.txt"* to whatever your filename is. Also, the data will be written in *out.csv*. What do you mean it's not working?

Comment: you are right, however if i wanted to add other columns from the csv file i am reading..how do i do that?

Comment: Just like you'd do in your own code. First, when reading data:  `value = d.get(key, [0, 0, some_other_column_0])` (plus the *some\_other\_column\_0* retrieval in the *try* block, like any of the current columns), and then when writing it to file add an `,{:}` before `\n` for each extra column. That's pretty much it.

Comment: The code should have answered your question. Is this the case?